# Recursive Stack Overflow & Odd Object Reference Java

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, stack-overflow

```
private boolean[][] computeMainOutline(boolean[][] outline) {

    int pixelValue[][] = new int [width][height];

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
            if(pixelValue[x][y] == 0) {
            ArrayList<Point2D.Double> path = new ArrayList<>();
            findPath(x, y, outline, pixelValue, path );
            }
    return new boolean[1][1]; // to avoid compilation error
}

private void findPath(int x, int y, boolean[][] outline, int pixelValue [][], ArrayList<Point2D.Double> path ) {
    path.add( new Point2D.Double(x, y));

    if(x > 0 && outline[x - 1][y] == true) // check right
        findPath(x - 1, y, outline, pixelValue, path);
    if(x < width && outline[x + 1][y] == true) // check left
        findPath(x + 1, y, outline, pixelValue, path);
    if(y < height && outline[x][y + 1] == true) // check up
        findPath(x, y + 1, outline, pixelValue, path ); 
    if(y > 0 && outline[x][y - 1] == true) // check down
        findPath(x, y - 1, outline, pixelValue, path);
}
```

The above method is giving a `StackOverflowError` and I don't know why.

The method `computeMainOutline` iterates through the whole `outline` array and the `pixelValue` array which are both the same size. If the "value" has not been calculated for a specific coordinate then the `findPath` function  will recursively calculate a path. A path is basically how many  "true" array elements are next to each other. The method to calculate the value is not added but my first problem is finding a path.

Moreover if I put a print statement right after `path.add( new Point2D.Double( x, y));` to print `path.size()` inside the recursive method, the size sequence is not consistent it might print(1,2,3,4,2,3,4), why is that?

**UPDATE**

Corrected it like this, but it will still spark a stack overflow...

```
private boolean[][] computeMainOutline(boolean[][] outline) {

    int pixelValue[][] = new int [width][height];
    boolean visited[][] = new boolean[width][height];

    for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) 
            if(visited[x][y] == false) {
            ArrayList<Point2D.Double> path = new ArrayList<>();
            findPath(x, y, outline, pixelValue, path, visited );
            }
    return new boolean[1][1]; // to avoid compilation error
}

private void findPath(int x, int y, boolean[][] outline, int pixelValue [][], ArrayList<Point2D.Double> path, boolean visited [][] ) {
    path.add( new Point2D.Double(x, y));
    visited[x][y] = true;

    if( x > 0  && visited[x - 1][y] == false && outline[x - 1][y] == true) // check right
        findPath(x - 1, y, outline, pixelValue, path, visited);
    if( x < width - 1 &&visited[x + 1][y] == false && outline[x + 1][y] == true) // check left
        findPath(x + 1, y, outline, pixelValue, path, visited);
    if( y < height - 1 && visited[x][y + 1] == false && outline[x][y + 1] == true) // check up
        findPath(x, y + 1, outline, pixelValue, path, visited ); 
    if( y > 0 && visited[x][y - 1] == false && outline[x][y - 1] == true) // check down
        findPath(x, y - 1, outline, pixelValue, path, visited);
}
```

Comment: If you don't mark already visited outline elements `findPath` will recurese infinitely because you will be adding to path same points

Answer (score 0):

The way you have done your recursion is wrong. While making a recursive method each call puts the previous call on a stack. If you're recursion runs forever there won't be enough room in the stack to go one level deeper causing a Stack Overflow.

Here's the problem. You haven't marked at each time step what has been visited. Imagine this is your grid. The cell in quotes is the `(x,y)` of our method

```
"T" F F                  T  F F               "T" F F
 T  F F   (next step)   "T" F F    (next)      T  F F
 T  F F                  T  F F                T  F F
```

It goes back to the state it's already visited. Hence you'll put infinite method calls in the stack.

**Solution**

Pass another array to the method with what cells have been visited and as you go to a cell mark it as visited. This would avoid you going back to something you've seen before

Comment: Will the array be changed when it's passed in as an argument? I know it's an object but it seems like it won't change... I should return it, right?

Comment: @Chris Arrays are not primitives, even if they are arrays of primitives. If you pass an array to a function and that function modifies the *contents* of the array, the change will be visible outside the function.

Comment: @Ordous well... I knew but... it still doesn't explain why I still get an overflow ... please check the update edit.

Comment: @Chris You'll find that the exception is only the start of your problems, the method will also return garbage output (unless you are specifically tracing the search steps, rather than want the path). IMHO the best advice here is: make a small example where it fails (3x3 sounds like a good start), think of a limit on stack depth for this (if it visits each cell once, then it should finish 9 cells in 10 recursive calls or less), and breakpoint in your IDE when it hits that stack depth (by keeping a "level" variable). Then analyze each frame, its state, and find out why it was able to get so deep